# Data migration in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a Oracle database. It has a table called USR_INFO and has following columns.

1. U_ID
2. U_NAME
3. U_ROLE

The U_ROLE can be a value of "A", "B" or "C".

Now i want to create a new table called ROLE_INFO having following columns

1. ROLE_ID
2. ROLE_NAME
3. ROLE_TAG

The task is to query in USR_INFO and look for U_ROLE == "B", and then if it matches
then copy U_ID to ROLE_ID and U_NAME to ROLE_NAME. I want to do that for all rows
in USR_INFO. While doing that, i also want to insert "BB" to ROLE_TAG.

Once am done with copying all data to ROLE_INFO. I want to search for U_ROLE == "B"
in USR_INFO and delete all those rows without affecting others.

This is what i did so far.

Create new Table called ROLE_INFO

```
CREATE TABLE ROLE_INFO 
(
    ROLE_ID INT,
    ROLE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    ROLE_TAG VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Now for copying, i did this,

```
INSERT INTO ROLE_INFO (ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME)

SELECT U_ID, U_NAME

FROM USR_INFO

WHERE U_ROLE == "B"
```

// ***When i do the insert, how to make sure that ROLE_TAG gets populated with "BB"?***

For deleting

```
DELETE FROM USR_INFO

WHERE U_ROLE == "B";
```

// ***Will this just delete the row that's already been copied to ROLE_INFO? Or will it delete more?***

Comment: Technically, this question does not involve migration, perhaps restructuring. Migration will usually imply moving the data from DB to DB, most cases a different DB type (i.e Oracle to SQL server and such). Other than that - a well structured question, kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the insert this way to add "BB" to your insert statement (note the single `=` instead of `==`) . Also replace `"B"` with `'B'` in your where clause.

```
INSERT INTO ROLE_INFO (ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME , ROLE_TAG)
SELECT U_ID, U_NAME,'BB'
FROM USR_INFO
WHERE U_ROLE='B';

COMMIT;

DELETE FROM USR_INFO
WHERE U_ROLE='B';

COMMIT;
```

Since your select statement and the delete statement is checking for the same condition the delete statement will only remove the rows where U_ROLE="B" (please note you need to use single equals as well).

Also once you perform the insert statement, you need to issue a commit statement so that the changes are persisted and visible.